# iPhone UISwitch looks different on 2 Mac. both have English environment

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

On my mac, Xcode 4.2, the switch control has an on/off look. but on my client's Mac, it has a circle/line look, that we see when the iphone language is set as non-english. my client confirmed that his setting is English and apple sample app has the on/off contrl look. the uiswitch control is created programmatically. any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of experiments I figured it out myself. it turned out if I add a English localization for the xib that is generated for the same .m I create UISwitch programmatically, then it has a correct on-off look on my client's Mac.